# How do I fix this exception in this code?

Tags: c#, kinect

What is wrong in this code? I've copied the code from a book exactly as it was and unfortunately it doesn't work. I get this exception and I don't know how to fix it. The exception is for this line

```
 KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
```

Exception is: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

This is complete code:

```
using Microsoft.Kinect;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
                sensor.DepthStream.Enable();
                sensor.DepthFrameReady += sensor_DepthFrameReady;

                // make it look like The Matrix 
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                // start the data streaming 
                sensor.Start();
                while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

        private static void sensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {
                if (depthFrame == null)
                    return;
                short[] bits = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
                depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(bits);
                foreach (var bit in bits)
                    Console.Write(bit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception>

Comment: Why do people consistently post questions with the line "my code throws an exception" without including the details in the question? The only way to know what the problem is would be to run the provided code, which most of the time is not complete or requires references we can't know about. </rant>

Comment: I'd suggest reading that the words in your exception. If you don't understand what it means, google 'index out of range'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the error comes from the line

```
 KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
```

which is an enumeration of available Kinect sensors and that the error states that the position `0` is empty, I would guess that your pc or the code cannot find a Kinect sensor.

If you put a breakpoint there and inspected the array of sensors im betting you would find that it is empty.

Suggestions:

- Have you connected the sensor
- Can it be found in the device manager
- Drivers installed??
- Tried turning it off and on again? :)
- Drink more coffe
- Solve with hammer.